# How to deal with Service Names with spaces in InstallShield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

I am creating an InstallShield package that installs a third party service using IS 2010 professional.  The service name has spaces in it, but this version of IS does not allow spaces in the service name, so I used a name without spaces not knowing any better.  This causes an error when the package is installed because the service name trying to be started cannot be found.  I tried creating a public property that had the correct name - with the spaces, but it doesn't use the property value.  Other than upgrading InstallShield, is there any way around this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such limitation.  What project type are you using and how exactly are you creating the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this has been corrected in later versions - I may have to upgrade:

Installshield has fixed this issue in their Installshield 2011 and Professional editions.

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=Q208910

IOA-000054509 (Basic MSI, InstallScript MSI, Merge Module, Transform)

It is now possible to add to a component a service that has one or more spaces in its name. Previously, InstallShield displayed an error if you tried to use spaces in a service name.

EDIT:  In case anyone comes across this issue, I was able to overcome it by going to the direct Editor in InstallShield, then clicked on Service control.  There, I was able to edit the name for the service - putting in the spaces.  This changed it on the component under Advanced Settings as well.  The installer now had the correct service nema to start and was able to do so.